# How do you use a KeyValueMap created through platform API inside a KeyValueMapOperations policy

Tags: apigee

I created a key/value map using the platform API defined [in this doc](http://apigee.com/docs/api/create-keyvalue-map). I used the API-scoped url to create a key/value map named **countrymap**.

> `https://api.enterprise.apigee.com/v1/o/{org_name}/apis/{api_name}/keyvaluemaps`

and plugged in the sample weather api I made while following the tutorials.

However I could not seem to refer to this map when I added a **KeyValueMapOperations** policy inside the API proxy. I tried adding a `mapIdentifier="countrymap"` to the definition (based on the [samples](http://apigee.com/docs/api-services/content/persist-data-using-keyvaluemap)) but it still does not see it.

```
<KeyValueMapOperations async="false" continueOnError="false" enabled="true" mapIdentifier="countrymap" name="keyvaluemapoperations-2">
    <DisplayName>KeyValueMapOperations-2</DisplayName>
    <FaultRules/>
    <Properties/>
    <ExclusiveCache>false</ExclusiveCache>
    <ExpiryTimeInSecs>-1</ExpiryTimeInSecs>
    <Get assignTo="my.country" index="1">
        <Key>
            <Parameter ref="apigee.countryCode"></Parameter>
        </Key>
    </Get>
    <Scope>organization</Scope>
</KeyValueMapOperations>
```

The policy works if I add an `<InitialEntries>` definition to the code above.

According to the Key/Value Maps docs:

> Key/ValueMaps provide an API for storing arbitrary name/value pairs
>   that can be access at runtime by **custom policies**, or for other custom
>   runtime requirements such as protocol support.

Do custom policies include the KeyValueMapOperations policy? What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you mentioned, you put the KeyValueMap in the scope of the api. To access that KVM, you'll need to use:

```
<Scope>apiproxy</Scope>
```

See the details for configuring the policy [here](http://apigee.com/docs/api-services/content/persist-data-using-keyvaluemap#-a-class-jumplink-name-configure-a-configuring-the-keyvaluemapoperation-policy).

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: Verify if teh keyvalumap is correctly created:
/v1/o/{org_name}/apis/{api_name}/keyvaluemaps" --> this should list the countrymap KVM

Step 2: Populate the KVM before trying to do a GET call on it.You can populate it either by using API Calls (apigee.com/docs/api/api_methods/62-update-keyvaluemap) , or by Using PUT operation of KeyValueMapOperations as shown here (apigee.com/docs/api-services/content/persist-data-using-keyvaluemap)

Step 3: Check the entries of KVM
/v1/o/{org_name}/apis/{api_name}/keyvaluemaps/countrymap

Step 4: You can use the same KeyValueMapOperations Polices as given in example to do a get on the KVM

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. The KVM is correctly created, and I successfully added entries to it. But the KVM policy doesn't get it. How do I specify which map the policy will access? Is doing `mapIdentifier="countrymap"` correct?

Comment: doing mapIdentifier="countrymap" is correct.Below is an working example: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<KeyValueMapOperations mapIdentifier="pathmap" enabled="true" continueOnError="false" async="false" name="FetchPath">
 <DisplayName>FetchPath</DisplayName>
  <FaultRules/>
    <Properties/>
    <ExclusiveCache>false</ExclusiveCache>
    <ExpiryTimeInSecs>-1</ExpiryTimeInSecs>
    <Get index="1" assignTo="targetpath">
        <Key><Parameter ref="current.flow.name"></Parameter></Key>
    </Get>
   <Scope>organization</Scope>
</KeyValueMapOperations>
`

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing this issue and after making below change in KeyValueMapOperations, it started working for me.

```
<Scope>apiproxy</Scope>
<Parameter>apigee.countryCode</Parameter>
```